# Express routes with same path but different parameters

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express

I have 2 methods:

- validateRegistration(), which calls app.get('/users/:email', todo)
- login(), which calls app.get('/users/:username', todo)

validateRegistration() works fine, but when login() is called, it returns null, but then if i comment out app.get('/users/:email', todo) in server.js, login() returns the expected response. It seems like both cannot exist together in server.js

See relevant code below

**registerPage.html**

```html
<div class="container" ng-show="show">
  <form name="registerForm" novalidate>

   <h2>Registration</h2>
   <span>All fields required</span>
   <br>
   <br>
   <label>First Name</label>
   <br>
   <input class="form-control" type="text" ng-model="user.fName" name="fName" required placeholder="First Name">
   <div ng-messages="registerForm.fName.$error">
    <div class="errorMsg" ng-message="required">Required</div>
   </div>
   
   <br>
   <label>Last Name</label>
   <input class="form-control" type="text" ng-model="user.lName" name="lName" required placeholder="Last Name">
   <div ng-messages="registerForm.lName.$error">
    <div class="errorMsg" ng-message="required">Required</div>
   </div>

   <br>
   <label>Email</label>
   <input class="form-control" ng-model="user.email" ng-change="validateEmail(user.email)" type="email" name="emailAdd" required placeholder="Email">
   <span class="errorMsg">{{emailExistsMsg}}</span>

   <div ng-messages="registerForm.emailAdd.$error">
    <div class="errorMsg" ng-message="email">Invalid email address</div>
    <div class="errorMsg" ng-message="required">Required</div>
   </div>

   <br>
   <label>Username</label>
   <input class="form-control" ng-model="user.username" ng-change="validateUsername(user.username)" type="text" name="uName" required placeholder="Username">
   <span class="errorMsg">{{usernameExistsMsg}}</span>
   <div ng-messages="registerForm.uName.$error">
    <div class="errorMsg" ng-message="required">Required</div>
   </div>

   <br>
   <label>Password</label>
   <input class="form-control" ng-minlength="6" type="password" ng-model="user.password" name="password" required placeholder="Password">
   <div ng-messages="registerForm.password.$error">
    <div class="errorMsg" ng-message="minlength">Password should be 6 character minimum</div>
    <div class="errorMsg" ng-message="required">Required</div>
   </div>

   <br>
   <button class="btn btn-info" ng-click="addUser(user)" ng-disabled="registerForm.$invalid">Register</button>
   <br>
   <br>
   <a href="#/signIn">Already registered?......<strong>Log In</strong></a>
 </form>
</div>
```

**registerController.js**

```js
myApp.controller('RegisterController', ['$scope', '$http', '$location', function($scope, $http, $location) {
 console.log("Register controller");

 $scope.addUser = function(user) {
  console.log("Add user called");
  $http.post('/users', {fname: user.fName, lname: user.lName, email: user.email, username: user.username, password: user.password}).success(function(response) {
   console.log("Add user response username: " + response.username);
  });

  this.validateRegistration(user.email);
 };

 $scope.validateEmail = function(email) {
  console.log("Validate email called");
  $http.get('/users/' + email).success(function(response) {
   if(response != null) {
    $scope.emailExistsMsg = response.email + " already exists";
   } else {
    $scope.emailExistsMsg = "";
   }
  });
 };

 $scope.validateRegistration = function(email) {
  $http.get('/users/' + email).success(function(response) {
   if(response != null) {
    console.log("Registration successful");
    $scope.registrationMsg = "Congratulations " + email + ". Registration successful";
    console.log($scope.registrationMsg);
    $location.path("/registrationStatus");

   } else {
    console.log("Registration not successful: " + response);
    $scope.registrationMsg = "Error with registration. Please try again or contact administrator.";
    console.log($scope.registrationMsg);
    $location.path("/registrationStatus");
   }
  });
 };
}]);
```

**signinPage.html**

```html
<div class="container" ng-show="show">

 <br>
 <form name="signInForm" novalidate>
  <h2>Sign In</h2>
  <br>
  <label>Username</label>
  <input class="form-control" ng-model="user.username" type="text" name="username" required placeholder="Username">
  <br>
  <label>Password</label>
  <input class="form-control" ng-model="user.password" type="password" name="password" required placeholder="Password">
  <br>
  <button class="btn btn-info" ng-click="logIn(user.username, user.password)" ng-disabled="signInForm.$invalid">Sign In</button>
  <br>
  <br>
  <a href="#/register">Not registered?......<strong>Register</strong></a>
 </form>

</div>
```

**signinController.js**

```js
myApp.controller('SignInController', ['$scope', '$http', '$location', function($scope, $http, $location) {
 console.log("Sign in controller");

 $scope.logIn = function(username, password) {
  console.log("Sign in called");

  $http.get('/users/' + username).success(function(response) {
   if(response != null) {
    if(username == response.username && password == response.password) {
     console.log("Successful log in");
     this.isDisabled = false;
     $location.path("/playSet");
    }
   } else {
    console.log("User not found: " + response);
   }
  });
 };
}]);
```

**server.js**

```js
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var mongojs = require('mongojs');
var db = mongojs('tracks', ['tracks']);
var db1 = mongojs('setlist', ['setlist']);
var db2 = mongojs('users', ['users']);
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

app.use(express.static(__dirname = '\public'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.get('/users/:email', function(req, res) {
 var email = req.params.email;
 console.log("Existing email validation: " + email);
 db2.users.findOne({email: email}, function(err, doc) {
  res.json(doc);
 });
});

app.get('/users/:username', function(req, res) {
 var username = req.params.username;
 console.log("User: " + username);
 db2.users.findOne({username: username}, function(err, doc) {
  res.json(doc);
 });
});

app.listen(3000);
console.log("Server running on port 3000");
```

Answer (score 11):

You can't have two separate routes:

```
app.get('/users/:email', ...);
app.get('/users/:username', ...);
```

because the second one will NEVER get hit because the first one matches the same thing.  You have the following options:

1. Change the path of one so it is unique from the other.
2. Combine them into one route handler and devise how to tell which piece of logic you want to execute from other conditions (query parameters, cookies, session state, etc...).
3. Use a more involved route definition (perhaps including a regex) so that each route definition you actually tell the difference between the two routes.

If (and I'm only guessing a bit from your context), you're trying to support two separate ways of identifying a user (one a user name and the other an email address), then I'd suggest you combine them both into one route handler and then just examine the `:username` value to see whether it is a username or an email address and act accordingly inside your route.  This could work if the `@` sign was not allowed in usernames but was required in email address.  Then, you could just check to see if the `req.params.username` contained an `@` sign and, if so, branch to the email address logic.

```
// single route handler to handle either a username or email lookup
app.get('/users/:username', function(req, res) {
    var username = req.params.username;
    if (username.indexOf("@") !== -1) {
        console.log("Existing email validation: " + username);
        db2.users.findOne({email: username}, function(err, doc) {
            res.json(doc);
        });
    } else {
        console.log("User: " + username);
        db2.users.findOne({username: username}, function(err, doc) {
            res.json(doc);
        });
    }
});
```

Or, perhaps a little more DRY:

```
// single route handler to handle either a username or email lookup
app.get('/users/:username', function(req, res) {
    // lookup either email address or username
    let name = req.params.username;
    let lookupObj = name.indexOf("@") !== -1 ? {email: name} : {username: name};
    db2.users.findOne(lookupObj, function(err, doc) {
        res.json(doc);
    });
});
```

Or, you can make the routes separate with unique paths:

```
app.get('/users/email/:email', ...);
app.get('/users/userID/:username', ...);
```

Comment: Great. Thank you. I appended each route with "/email" and "/username" respectively.

Comment: @bcooley1983 - If one of these answers provided an answer to your question, then you should indicate that to the community by click the green checkmark next to the best answer. That will also earn you some reputation points for following the proper procedure.

Answer (score 2):

It's been 4+ years since this question was posted and I had a similar issue.

I want to relate how I solved this problem. It might be helpful. In brief, I converted the controllers to middleware.

What I had initially

```js
app.get('/users/:email', ...);
app.get('/users/:id', ...);
```

I removed the

```js
app.get('/users/:email', ...)
```

and made it into

```js
app.get('/users', getUserByEmail, ...otherControllers)
```

Then, in `getUserByEmail`, I check if the `email` property exists on the `req.query` object, AND ALSO if it is the only property on the query object, search for the user by email, else, execute the next function to move to the next controller/middleware.

```js
 if(req.query.email !== undefined && Object.keys(req.query).length === 1){
   ... code to get user by email
   end if block with return
  }
  next()
```

Comment: here, you are using controllers as middleware, which doesn't seem like a good practice!

Comment: @RahulSoni you are right.
I could have used a middleware itself to reroute the request to the necessary handlers. The logic is still okay I think

Answer (score 1):

These are not unique routes.

The first route that matches a given path is the one that gets used, regardless of the parameters supplied.

Here you have route `/users/` with the `email` parameter, followed by the same route `/users/` with the `username` parameter, which will never be evaluated.

If you want to use this style of routing, you should have one `/users/` route that takes a parameter, and then in that route evaluate the parameter to determine if it is an `email` or a `username`, and then execute the appropriate find on the database.  This is not an easy or foolproof method, and limits the possibility that someone could use their email address as a username, among other things.  Therefore, you should **strongly** consider using unique routes, like `/users/email/:email` or something similar.

Personally, I think your issue is additionally confused by the fact that you seem to want to use `/users/` for both registration and login.  You *probably* should use something like `/login/` and `/register/` instead, especially so that you could use `/users/` later to fetch a list of users.  however, if you **must** use the same route, you **could** separate them by `get` and `post`, since `post` is more common with registration type scenarios anyway.

Overall, it feels like you need to take a bit more time evaluating your overall API uses and purpose, to decide the right way to structure your endpoints.