# Can we pass multiple params on same route node js?

Tags: node.js, express

router.route('/user/:userId')
router.route('/user/:emailId')

Both are get operations. But only one works which comes first.

I need either of them to trigger based on params.
There are PUT and DELETE methods on :userId.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Express routes with same path but different parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40370363/express-routes-with-same-path-but-different-parameters)

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can get multiple params in single route ins express JS like this.

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const port = 3000

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send('hello world')
});

app.get('/user/:userId/:emailId', (req, res) => {
  const {
    userId,
    emailId
  } = req.params
  res.json({
    userId,
    emailId
  });
});

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Example app listening at http://localhost:${port}`)
});
```